# Is it a good practice to instantiate a HashSet from an IEnumerable before using Contains()?

Tags: c#, performance, time-complexity, hashset, premature-optimization

The piece of code below filters an `IEnumerable<T>` with another, used as a blacklist. The filtered collection iterates over content fetched remotely (lazy loading, YouTube API).

```
IEnumerable<CustomType> contentThatCanBeHuge = this.FetchContentThatCanBeHuge();
IEnumerable<string> blackListContent = this.FetchBlackListContent();
return contentThatCanBeHuge.Where(x => !blackListContent.Contains(x.Id));
```

The `Enumerable.Contains` method is O(n) in time complexity, so the `Enumerable.Where` call could take a while.

In the other hand, `HashSet<T>.Contains` is O(1). Instantiating a `HashSet<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` seems to be O(n).

If the blacklist is about to **be used multiple times**, and without taking space complexity into account, is it a good approach to turn it into a `HashSet<T>` before using it or is this just premature optimization?

Comment: How many (approximately, not exactly) are the items?

Comment: The variables are not used in the query.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, very variable, `contentThatCanBeHuge` can enumerate all videos from a YouTube channel.

Comment: What is the type of the `Id` property? Does this type have an efficient `GetHashCode` implementation?

Comment: @Emond, No. I'm looking for general good practices.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, `Id` is a `string`.

Comment: The answer is no. Even if you do find that this is on the critical performance path, hashing may not necessarily be the best option to make it faster.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks. Considering Dmitry's answer, could you elaborate?

Comment: The answer is yes. We are talking about different complexity classes here, so definitely *not* premature optimization, and definitely *not* something that we need to measure. Assuming that the blacklist is not so huge that memory would be an issue, I would consider it a bug if I were to see a colleague write such code as above.

Comment: The `x.Id` does not make any sense if `contentThatCanBeHuge` contains strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let size of `blackListContent` be `m` and size of `contentThatCanBeHuge` is `n`.

If we **don't use** `HashSet`, time complexity is `O(n * O(m))` = `O(n * m)`, space complexity is `O(1)`: for each item in `contentThatCanBeHuge` we should scan entire `blackListContent`.

If we **use** `HashSet`, time complexity is `O(m) + O(n * O(1))` = `O(n + m)`, space complexity is `O(m)`:

1. We create `HashSet` - `O(m)` time complexity, `O(m)` space complexity.
2. For each item in `contentThatCanBeHuge` we should check it with rspect of HashSet - `O(n * O(1))` time complexity.

So far so good `HashSet` makes the code *faster* but we consumes more memory.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. The choice will depend on which is more costly: storing the data in memory or iterating it each time. And since the data of the blacklist is retrieved remotely, it _might be better_ to store it in memory.

Comment: *Might be better* is an understatement. The circumstances would be rather exceptional if they forced you to choose an `O(nm)` solution over an `O(n+m)` one, *especially* if the `IEnumerable` is fetched via lazy loading. Depending on the implementation, it may not even support multiple enumeration.